# Throwing Exceptions with Mockito in Kotlin

Tags: java, testing, kotlin, mockito

I am using Kotlin and am trying to throw an Exception on a specific method invocation but always get the following error

```
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: exceptions.ServiceException
```

This is the test

```
val client : IClient = Mockito.spy(Client(Cnf("https://:region.example.com", key)))


@Test(expected = ServiceException::class)
fun test400ResponseFrom() {
    val url = "https://example.com/example/user/v3/user/by-name/JACKAPPLE"

    Mockito.doThrow(ServiceException("Bad Request")).`when`(client).makeRequest(url ,riotkey)
    client.getUserDataByNameAndRegion("jackapple", "BR")
}
```

Basically the `getUserDataByNameAndRegion` method will invoke the `makeRequest` method and with this test I want to validate that the method is handling the result of the stubbed method correctly.

The original method looks like this

```
@Throws(NotFoundException::class, ServiceException::class)
fun makeRequest(url: String, key : String) : String {
    val con = prepareConnection(url, key)
    val statusCode = con.responseCode
    when {
        (statusCode == 400) -> throw ServiceException("Bad Request")
        (statusCode == 401) -> throw ServiceException("Unauthorized")
        (statusCode == 403) -> throw ServiceException("Forbidden")
        (statusCode == 404) -> throw NotFoundException("Data not Found")
        (statusCode == 415) -> throw ServiceException("Unsupported Media Type")
        (statusCode == 429) -> throw ServiceException("Rate limit exceeded")
        (statusCode == 500) -> throw ServiceException("Internal Server Error")
        (statusCode == 502) -> throw ServiceException("Bad Gateway")
        (statusCode == 503) -> throw ServiceException("Service unavailable")
        (statusCode == 504) -> throw ServiceException("Gateway timeout")
        (statusCode == 200) -> {
            return getStringResponseFromConnection(con)
        }
        else -> {
            throw ServiceException("Respondend with Statuscode ${statusCode}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

You can try the following idea (taken from similar [discussion on github](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/issues/192#issuecomment-399007630)):

```
.doAnswer { throw ServiceException("Bad Request") }
```

Comment: this works for me, the `answer` function seems to work. `given(yourClass.someMethod()).willAnswer { throw ServiceException() }`

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was using an underlying Java client that threw checked exceptions. My Kotlin code needed to handle one variation of these exceptions and so to test this code path I was able to use:

```
whenever(someObject.doesSomething(any()).then {
    throw MyCheckedException("Error")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```java
`when`(someClassMocked.muFunction).thenThrow(SocketException())
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin does not support [creating methods that throw checked exceptions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html). You can either define `makeRequest` in Java, or change `ServiceException` to extend `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Just because Kotin doesn't distinguish between checked and unchecked exceptions doesn't mean you can't throw or catch a checked exception within Kotlin code.

Comment: Yes. But that's not what I said. As the page I linked says:
> Kotlin does not have checked exceptions. There are many reasons for this, but ...